# Do not understand Region class very well

Tags: android, canvas, xamarin, region

I using xamarin to develop a android app. When I try to use Region class I got a problem, below code can work well and show a expected blue area.

```
Rect rect1 = new Rect(0, 0, 10,10);
canvas.ClipRect(rect1);
Rect rect2 = new Rect(20, 20, 30,30);
canvas.ClipRect(rect2, Region.Op.Union);
canvas.DrawRect(0, 0, 40, 40, paint);
```

But below code does not work, just show nothing, a blank background

```
Region region = new Region();
Rect rect1 = new Rect(0, 0, 10,10);
region.Union(rect1);
Rect rect2 = new Rect(20, 20, 30,30);
region.Union(rect2);

canvas.ClipRegion(region);
canvas.DrawRect(0, 0, 40, 40, paint);
```

I do not know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it works, but it  may be blocked by your `ActionBar` or something others, so you cant see it and you think it does not work, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DT2J.png). But if you modify the coordinates you can see the rectangle which you draw. Here is my code and result:

```
Region region = new Region();
Rect rect1 = new Rect(200, 200, 300, 300);
region.Union(rect1);
Rect rect2 = new Rect(400, 400, 500, 500);
region.Union(rect2);
```

Here is the [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Graphics.Canvas.ClipRegion/p/Android.Graphics.Region/) to explain the `canvas.ClipRegion(region)` method:

> Intersect the current clip with the specified region. Note that unlike clipRect() and clipPath() which transform their arguments by the current matrix, clipRegion() assumes its argument is already in the coordinate system of the current layer's bitmap, and so not transformation is performed.

**EDIT :**

Coordinate for [clipRect()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkDK0.png), coornadite for [clipRegion()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0yfZ.png).

Comment: Thanks. I changed my coordinate and shapes can be displayed. But I do not agree your explanation. If ActionBar or something else covers my shape and cause it can not be seen in second case then why those shapes can be seen in first case?

Comment: Note that unlike clipRect() and clipPath() which transform their arguments by the current matrix, means for clipRect() method, its coordinate is the current matrix, the space it will be placed. But for ClipRegion() method, its coordinate is the  current layer's bitmap, the phone screen. Their coordinate is different.

Comment: I try to do more to make me understand. Anyway I close this thread, thanks a lot.